# Typescript - translation strings typings solution?

Tags: typescript, types, internationalization, translation, typescript-typings

I'm using this object format to store translation strings for multiple languages:

```
export const Translations = {
  'en': {
    text1: 'Hello world!',
    text2: 'Login'
  }
  'cs': {
    text1: 'Ahoj svět!',
    text2: 'Přihlášení'
  }
}
```

Then I have my state and an interface for the state defined:

```
export const MyState: State = {
  lang: 'cs',
  trans: Translations.cs,
}

export type State = {
  lang: LangCodes,
  trans: ???
}
```

Now I would need somehow to define that `MyState.trans` can contain only names of translation properties, which means `text1, text2` in this case. Something that enables type checkings an autocomplete feature in editor for this object (when using like this: `MyState.trans.text1`). Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe union of all possible/allowed state should help:

```js
export const Translations = {
  'en': {
    text1: 'Hello world!',
    text2: 'Login'
  },
  'cs': {
    text1: 'Ahoj svět!',
    text2: 'Přihlášení'
  }
} as const

type Translations = typeof Translations
type LangCodes = keyof Translations

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// Make union of all allowed states
type Union = {
  [P in LangCodes]: {
    lang: P,
    trans: Translations[P]
  }
}

// get all values of the union
type State = Values<Union>

export const MyState: State = {
  lang: 'cs',
  trans:Translations.cs
} // ok

export const MyWrongState: State = {
  lang: 'cs',
  trans:Translations.en
} // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wCpQIZoDbYwCWKqcAvHAN4BQccA5MMgwFzV31wygwCM7BgAlgePBDgB3aHgAmAQgYAaTvR4gYAJkEAZCAHMiLTgF8V9BglRsOXbrwGMAggAsIAKzioAboGxAGIrmXOpaggAKgJqARC54AIeAhoDMALcMpjQmcNhkSGgwNDQwAJ5gwHBYuKgExKQU3MXAEABmZTj4hCRoBfVwOrj6AMIQssBklADWwIVNLRVVHaj5RSVwAGrYeACuIwA8GAB8tRgA2hNTzRgAuovdAKrIHbW09EdhcEY9fYPDqBfsT1wEZD6dhhIJqVqodjlNrVNAvK70Ezpa7LADKMEIpUoa02OzuHT2%20VAkFgiFI8AAsoV0Zj2DSeI9OIDgYwrMpODAIaxoZV2qQAHRWdJwAD0IrgEDGRPA0HgOXQcCpAHUoCh9PTgHSMQzKP9mYI2UFORVuRC5gLmMKxXBgFBVVAaEA)

P.S. My main goal is to make invalid state unrepresentable

Comment: Thanks. In my case simple `trans: typeof Translations.cs | typeof Translations.en` is sufficient.